# C# Async method call all the way to Main

Tags: c#, async-await

Can someone clarify this example, which of course, is not working:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)//main cant' be async
    {
        int res = test();//I must put await here

        Console.WriteLine("END");
    }

    public async static Task<int> test()
    { //why can't I make it just: public int test()??
        int a1, a2, a3, a4;

        a1 = await GetNumber1();
        a2 = await GetNumber2();
        a3 = await GetNumber3();

        a4 = a1 + a2 + a3;
        return a4;
    }

    public static async Task<int> GetNumber1()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("GetNumber1");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            });
        return 1;
    }
```

I am trying to "collect" values from GenNumberX methods by using "await". I would like to make method "test" not async somehow. I dont understand why test has to be async when I am using await to get a value. This example makes me to write async on every method where I use async, and when I drill up to Main, I cannot make it async?

How to write real-world example:

```
public bool ReserveAHolliday()
{
        bool hotelOK = await ReserveAHotel();//HTTP async request
        bool flightOK = await ReserveFlight();////HTTP async request
        bool result = hotelOK && flightOK;
        return result;
}
```

How to make method *ReserveAHolliday* synchronous?
Am I missing something or don't understand the use of async-await mechanism?

Comment: At some point you're going to need to start an asynctask from a synchronous method. If you want to to fire, simply call it (Also called async voids, fire and forget), or use `test().Wait()` which will wait on the task synchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below is a full example. you can run the ReserverAHoliday both Synchronously (bool r = ReserveAHolliday().Result;) and Asynchronously (just call ReserveAHolliday();) from MAIN (depends which line you comment). and you can see the effect ("END" gets printed before / after the reservation is complete).
I prefer the await Task.WhenAll() methods, which is more readable.
also note that it's preferred to use await Task.Delay(100) instead of Thread.sleep inside GetNumber1.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)//main cant' be async
    {
        //int res = test().Result;//I must put await here
        bool r = ReserveAHolliday().Result; //this will run Synchronously.
        //ReserveAHolliday(); //this option will run aync : you will see "END" printed before the reservation is complete.
        Console.WriteLine("END");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public async static Task<int> test()
    { //why can't I make it just: public int test()??
        //becuase you cannot use await in synchronous methods. 
        int a1, a2, a3, a4;

        a1 = await GetNumber1();
        a2 = await GetNumber1();
        a3 = await GetNumber1();

        a4 = a1 + a2 + a3;
        return a4;
    }

    public static async Task<int> GetNumber1()
    {
        //await Task.Run(() =>
        //    {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("GetNumber1");
                    await Task.Delay(100); // from what I read using Task.Delay is preferred to using  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
        //    });
        return 1;
    }

    public async static Task<bool> ReserveAHolliday()
    {
        //bool hotelOK = await ReserveAHotel();//HTTP async request
        //bool flightOK = await ReserveAHotel();////HTTP async request
        var t1 = ReserveAHotel("FirstHotel");
        var t2 = ReserveAHotel("SecondHotel");
        await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
        bool result = t1.Result && t1.Result;// hotelOK && flightOK;
        return result;
    }
    public static async Task<bool> ReserveAHotel(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reserve A Hotel started for "+ name);
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        if (name == "FirstHotel") 
            await Task.Delay(500); //delaying first hotel on purpose.
        Console.WriteLine("Reserve A Hotel done for " + name);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Guy. Can this example make deadlocks, like @Kabbalah mentioned in the above answer?
I should probably keep those methods async, since I am going to write a library for use in WinForms project. This code was just an axample. I am actually writing SignalR client/wrapper to enable communication between various softwares (ERP->POS, POS->ERP) with methods such: _IsUserOnline(string userId)_ , _GetOnlineUsers_, etc.

Comment: In WinForms, probably... it depends on what exactly happens in your library. Does your library code require a Synchronization Context? If the answer is yes it will most certainly deadlock. If the answer is no you might get away with this if you specify ConfigureAwait(false) in your library code. I'll edit my answer with more information.

Comment: I suggest spending time on this, so as not to get burned.
I think if you use await, you are safer, because you are in an async context, and the synchronous code that initially called the async method can continue its work...
to be extra sure of implication I suggest adding a long delay inside your async, so you can see the behavior impact for yourself.
also, I prefer launching such async from a bool property (propfull) that I use as a flag (so that the same task is not launched multiple times in parallel, when I don't want it to). I don't know if this applies to you and if it's good practice.

Answer (score 1):

> First of all never use **Result** it has a bad implementation and you
>   will end up having deadlocks. Instead use **GetAwaiter().GetResult()**

If you are using C# 7.0 or below then it's safe to use this pattern:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    private static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        await MyMethod();
        await MyOtherMethod();
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }

    private static async Task MyMethod()
    {
        // do something
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static async Task MyOtherMethod()
    {
        // do something
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

If you are using C# 7.1+ then you can change the main method to be an async one like this:

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await MyMethod();
        await MyOtherMethod();
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }

    private static async Task MyMethod()
    {
        // do something
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static async Task MyOtherMethod()
    {
        // do something
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

In .Net core project you can change to C# 7.1 or higher by using this tag:

```
<LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
```

or

```
<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
```

The project file will look like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    
 <PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>   
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your async needs to start somewhere, and since your program has a starting point, it's a synchronous method at this point. Most `async`'s start at what we like to call `async void`'s, which are basically fire and forget methods. It starts a task, and doesn't care what it returns. If you need to wait for something in a synchronous method, you can use the `.Wait()` method on a task, or use `.Result` to get the result of the task.

For your real world example, if you want to run both tasks at the same time, you would need to do something like this:

```
public async Task<bool> ReserveAHoliday()
{
        //Initialize and start this task
        Task<bool> hotelTask = ReserveAHotel();//HTTP async request
        //Initialize and start this task
        Task<bool> flightTask = ReserveFlight();////HTTP async request
        //Await until hotel task is done, and get the bool
        bool hotelOK = await hotelTask;
        //Await until flight task is done (This might have already finished while the hotel was grabbing, and get the bool
        bool flightOK = await flightTask;
        bool result = hotelOK && flightOK;
        //Return the final result
        return result;
}
```

I highly recommend watching [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Mads-Torgersen-Inside-C-Async). It gives a nice introduction to how Async works, and can jump start you in the wonderful world of Async.

Comment: _ReserveAHolliday_ wont' work because of using _await_ without declaring a method async. So it seems that I have to use _Task.Wait()_ method.

Comment: I've updated the example. ReserveAHoliday should be an async Task. Like I mentioned, I highly recommend you check out the video I linked. It will take a bit of time, but it's highly worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you FrankerZ for the right answer!
So my litle example should look something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = test();
        task.Wait(); //this stops async behaviour
        int result = task.Result;// get return value form method "test"
        Console.WriteLine("RESULT IS = " + result);
    }

    public async static Task<int> test()
    {
        int a1, a2, a3, a4;

        //run all tasks
        //all tasks are doing their job "at the same time"
        var taskA1 = GetNumber1();
        var taskA2 = GetNumber2();
        var taskA3 = GetNumber3();

        //wait for task results
        //here I am collecting results from all tasks
        a1 = await taskA1;
        a2 = await taskA2;
        a3 = await taskA3;

        //get value from all task results
        a4 = a1 + a2 + a3;
        return a4;
    }

    public static async Task<int> GetNumber1()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("GetNumber1");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            });
        return 1;
    }
```

//other methods are ommited because they are the same like GetNumber1
    }

Comment: `Task.Result` blocks until the task is complete so you don't need the `task.Wait()`

Comment: Be careful because this only works in a console application. If you try this in a WPF or Forms application it will most probably cause a deadlock. Please see the link in my post about this issue.

Comment: Don't use `Thread.Sleep(100)` - use `await Task.Delay(100)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `await` keyword inside a method, it has to be `async`. This was a design decision to make it easier to be backwards compatible.

`Main` cannot be `async` as it is the starting point of the program, so you typically need to block somehow to keep the program running. You can do that by blocking on a `Task` or even by calling `Console.ReadLine`.

Tasks usually execute on a background thread and background threads do not keep your program running if all foreground threads stop.

I've got an introductory blog post on `async-await` [here](http://www.nedstoyanov.com/async-await-what-is-it-and-how-do-i-use-it/)

Answer (score 0):

The method ReserveAHolliday cannot be made synchronous if you use the await keyword inside of it.

What could be possible is to simply block till both async methods return their value. I don't recommend it though because it could lead to deadlocks or other unexpected errors.

If you don't have a synchronization context (eg. console application) you can simply write

```
bool hotelOK = ReserveAHotel().Result;
```

But I reckon you ultimately want to create a GUI. That is where blocking falls apart. Because UI application (Forms and WPF) do have a context and waiting for asynchronous methods cause deadlocks. [Read more here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

There are workarounds for this problem, but they are highly dependent on the design of your application.

Edit:

If your library code needs Synchronization Context then blocking will most certainly cause a deadlock.

If you don't need it, it's possible to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in your library code and get away with blocking.

What I recommend is: async/await all the way or no async/await at all. There are other possibilities to make your code asynchronous, eg: event based, but like everything in life has pros and cons.

Please read [this blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) from Stephen Cleary. He explains why blocking async code will deadlock and how you can avoid it.

Comment: Yes, I am writing a library project, that is going to be used in WinForms GUI. If this can make some problems, I will keep these methods _async_, it is not big problem, I just wanted to design those classes in the way I planned, but this plan might be wrong.